# How delete in sql server a word in the whole column?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I just fill up my database with an excel file and after checking out it i saw that in many column there is an error.

I check out on internet and it is a bug of Excel when insert cells in multiline. So now the word "*x000D*" is present in many columns.

How i can delete it with a query with sql in the whole database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna do this on all your database, you have to create a procedure looping through

the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view, which will give you all columns (with their tables) of your database. You can check the DATA_TYPE of your columns (you don't need to update integer columns, for example)

Then with dynamic sql, build a query like that in the loop

```
UPDATE <MYTABLE> SET <MYCOLUMN> = REPLACE(<MYCOLUMN>, 'x000D', '')
```

and execute it.

**EDIT**

Faster, not so clean, without a stored proc, you can type in SQL Server Management studio :

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' 
+ c.TABLE_NAME 
+ ' SET ' 
+ c.COLUMN_NAME 
+ ' =REPLACE(' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ', ''x000D'', '''');'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' // or IN (<the types you wanna correct>)
```

you copy the result and execute it, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
update MyTable -- <<=== Your table name
set myColumn = null -- <<=== Your column name
where myColumn='x000D'
```

This query will clear out the value `x000D` from the `myColumn` in all rows that are set to `x000D`.

Answer (score 0):

Could be easier to trunk and reload the tables, with the corrected xls